# ffmpeg same bit rate in hls file across resolutions

Tags: ffmpeg, avplayer, http-live-streaming

We are using following command to generate dash and hls file for a given video:

```
ffmpeg -y -nostdin -loglevel error -i input.mp4 \
        -map 0:v:0  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:v:0  -map 0:v:0  -map 0:v:0  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a\?:0  \
        -maxrate:v:0 350k -bufsize:v:0 700k  -c:v:0 libx264 -filter:v:0 "scale=320:-2"  \
        -maxrate:v:1 1000k -bufsize:v:0 2000k -c:v:1 libx264 -filter:v:1 "scale=640:-2"  \
        -maxrate:v:2 3000k -bufsize:v:0 6000k -c:v:2 libx264 -filter:v:2 "scale=1280:-2" \
        -maxrate:v:3 245k -bufsize:v:3 600k -c:v:3 libvpx-vp9 -filter:v:3 "scale=320:-2"  \
        -maxrate:v:4 700k  -bufsize:v:3 1400k -c:v:4 libvpx-vp9 -filter:v:4 "scale=640:-2"  \
        -maxrate:v:5 2100k -bufsize:v:3 4200k -c:v:5 libvpx-vp9 -filter:v:5 "scale=1280:-2"  \
        -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v  id=1,streams=a" \
        -threads 8 -seg_duration 5 -hls_playlist true -f dash output/output.mpd
```

This works and generates hls files also as expected, one sample m3u8 file below:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="group_A1",NAME="audio_6",DEFAULT=YES,URI="media_6.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=129663,RESOLUTION=320x168,CODECS="avc1.64000c,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_0.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=129663,RESOLUTION=640x336,CODECS="avc1.64001e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_1.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=129663,RESOLUTION=1280x670,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_2.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=330756,RESOLUTION=320x168,CODECS="vp09.00.11.08,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_3.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=329663,RESOLUTION=640x336,CODECS="vp09.00.21.08,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_4.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=329663,RESOLUTION=1280x670,CODECS="vp09.00.31.08,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_5.m3u8
```

Now as you notice, the Bandwidth is same for resolution of `320x168`, `640x336` and `1280x670`, which might have happened because of nature of video.

But the issue with this is in iOS's AVPlayer it always picks the minimum resolution one and never picks the better resolution stream even if it is available because of same bitrate.

So the question I want to ask is: is there some option available to ensure - I always have some difference in the bitrates of different resolutions or more specific, bit rate always increase(may be just by few bytes) for increasing resolutions.

---

### EDIT

Earlier I was using `-b:v` option per output instead of `-maxrate:v`, I was getting following output for same video:

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=479663,RESOLUTION=320x168,CODECS="avc1.64000c,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_0.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1129663,RESOLUTION=640x336,CODECS="avc1.64001e,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_1.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3129663,RESOLUTION=1280x670,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="group_A1"
media_2.m3u8
```

If you see, Bandwidth has increased considerably, for the same video and same video quality, also all the file sizes also increased 4x. as par my understanding with `maxrate` option, `ffmpeg` optimises the output and provides only required bandwidth, while with `b:v` option it forcefully increases the bandwidth to given values without any benefit in terms of quality. So essentially you get same quality video at much higher bandwidth.

Which is why I want to use `maxrate` option but with increasing bandwidth. If I manually change the bandwidth to increasing order in the output with `maxrate` option, adaptive bit rate starts to work in iOS's AVPlayer.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-b:v` option per output with the appropriate stream specifiers like your other options. The resulting `BANDWIDTH` values will change accordingly.

Other stuff:

Consider adding `-bufsize` for each output: otherwise your `-maxrate` may be ignored.

Since you're performing the same filtering multiple times it would be more efficient to do all filtering in one filtergraph and use the split filter to duplicate effort:

```
-filer_complex "scale=320:-2,split[320a][320b];scale=640:-2,split[640a][640b];scale=1280:-2,split[1280][1280b]"
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes I am using bufsize, which I have also added now in the answer. I have been earlier using `-b:v` option earlier, but it increases the bit rate even for the cases where it is not needed, giving the same video quality. Thanks for the suggestion on optimisation.

Comment: @Saurabh So you want `BANDWIDTH` to change in `master.m3u8`, but you don't want to declare the bitrate with `-b:v`? Because this answer literally answers the original question, so I guess I don't really know what the issue is now. Secondly, have you verified that `BANDWIDTH` is the culprit here? Did you manually edit the file and change the values to test?

Comment: Hey, replied to your comments in the edit section of my question, I probably should had added this earlier itself to not cause any confusion.